# The components which is used to position HTML document either vertically and horizontally

Tags: html

I just came across these questions. I am not getting the answer. Can someone help

1. The components which is used to position HTML document either vertically and horizontally is
   a. Table
   b. Forms
   c. Frame
   d. Lists
2. Can we create both the vertical and horizontal frames in a webpage at the same time?

Comment: what do you mean? do you mean to center vertical or horizontally or to aling multiple items next to each other vertically or horizontally? what do you mean with frames? Block elements?

Comment: Even I am also not getting the question. My professor has asked me this. He said which element can be used to position a component vertically and horizontally. He must be talking about the center I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that would be table as you can create tables horizontally as well as vertically.
These are called Table Rows and Columns. Let me explain.

You basically create different  (table row) elements with inside a table header  or a table data element  inside a .

When you create 1 row with multiple data elements, you created a horizontal table.
When you create multiple rows with each one data element inside, you have created a vertical table.

I hope this answers your question.